# group results by min datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I try to get the first (lowest) start date of a employee:

```
SELECT a.StartDate, a.EmpID, b.fullname FROM Employees a 
LEFT JOIN dbo.info b ON a.EmpID = b.EmpID
WHERE 
    type = 800 
    GROUP By EmpId
    ORDER BY fullname
```

The result is similar to this:

```
StartDate | EmpId
1992-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 7
2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 7
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 7
1992-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 10
2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 10
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 10
1992-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 16
2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 16
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 16
```

To get the lowest date of each employee I tried this, but it resulted in an error.

```
SELECT MIN(a.StartDate), a.EmpID, b.fullname FROM Employees a 
LEFT JOIN dbo.info b ON a.EmpID = b.EmpID
WHERE 
    type = 800 
    GROUP By EmpId
    ORDER BY fullname
```

What is the correct query to get the result as below:

```
StartDate | EmpId
1992-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 7
1992-12-01 00:00:00.000 | 10
1992-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 16
```

Comment: SELECT MIN(StartDate), EmpID  ... group by EmpID?

Comment: @jarlh I rewrote the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.StartDate, a.EmpID, b.fullname 
FROM Employees a 
LEFT JOIN dbo.info b ON a.EmpID = b.EmpID
WHERE type = 800 
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
                 FROM Employees a2
                 WHERE a.EmpID = a2.EmpID
                 AND a2.StartDate < a.StartDate
               )
```

Answer (score 1):

You want a result row per `EmpID`, so that's the column you should group by:

```
SELECT   MIN(StartDate), EmpID 
FROM     Employees
WHERE    type = 800 AND EmpID BETWEEN 1 AND 500
GROUP BY EmpID
```

Comment: works for the query, but not in a left join query. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(StartDate), EmpID FROM Absences
WHERE type = 800 
AND EmpID BETWEEN 1 AND 500
GROUP BY StartDate
```

your group by is on the wrong field.

```
GROUP BY EmpID
```

Comment: also you might want to use HAVING on EmpID instead of WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Query, 
This will stop repeating data

```
  SELECT Distinct StartDate, EmpID FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.EmpID, b.fullname, a.StartDate FROM Employees a 
LEFT JOIN dbo.info b 
ON a.EmpID = b.EmpID
WHERE type = 800    
ORDER BY a.StartDate, b.fullname ASC
```

Comment: Belongs to Employees (updated question). I get: b.fullname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Check now solution. Here, we using distinct keyword for avoid duplicates. so, we doesnt need to group by.